# MSAL Confidential Client Authentication -- 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, microsoft-dynamics, azure-ad-msal

I am writing a script in python to authenticate to my Dynamics web api app and be able to perform operations (get/patch/post, etc). I am trying to authenticate via client credentials flow. I am able to authenticate and receive a token, but when I use the token in the header to make a patch to an entity, I am returned a 403 forbidden error with the message `requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url`

However, I am able to successfully post/edit my global options set with a 204 response. While it seems like a permissions issue with the 403 error, having success when posting to options sets within Dynamics makes me question if that is the issue if I can perform that operation. Has anyone seen this before?

Patch:

```
headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
        'OData-Version': '4.0',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Prefer': 'return=representation',
        'If-Match': 'null'
    }

response = requests.patch(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    print(response)
```

Post:

```
headers= {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
        'OData-Version': '4.0',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Prefer': 'return=representation',
        'If-Match': '*'
    }

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=json_data)
            print(response)
            response.raise_for_status()  # Check if the request was successful
```